# In-memory autocomplete implementation for small static data set in java

Tags: java, mongodb, algorithm, elasticsearch, data-structures

I am trying to implement an autocomplete feature for small set of static data 5K records.

I thought of using an prefix tree to support such queries

```
class AutocompleteSearch {
    class Entry {
        String sentence;
        int times;
        
        Entry(String sentence, int times) {
            this.sentence = sentence;
            this.times = times;
        }
    }
    
    class TrieNode {
        TrieNode[] children;
        int times;
        
        TrieNode() {
            children = new TrieNode[27];
            times = 0;
        }
    }
    
    private TrieNode root;
    private TrieNode previous;
    private String query;

    public AutocompleteSystem(String[] sentences, int[] times) {
        root = new TrieNode();
        query = "";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
            insert(sentences[i], times[i]);
        }
    }
    
    public List<String> input(char c) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (c == '#') {
            insert(query, 1);
            previous = null;
            query = "";
            return result;
        }
        
        query += c;
        List<Entry> history = lookup(c);
        history.sort((a, b) -> {
            if (a.times == b.times) {
                return a.sentence.compareTo(b.sentence);
            }
            return b.times - a.times;
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(history.size(), 3); i++) {
            result.add(history.get(i).sentence);
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    private void insert(String sentence, int times) {
        TrieNode current = root;
        for (char c : sentence.toCharArray()) {
            int index = c == ' ' ? 26 : c - 'a';
            if (current.children[index] == null) {
                current.children[index] = new TrieNode();
            }
            current = current.children[index];
        }
        current.times += times;
    }
    
    private List<Entry> lookup(char c) {
        List<Entry> history = new ArrayList<>();
        if (previous == null && query.length() > 1) {
            return history;
        }
        
        TrieNode current = previous == null ? root : previous;
        int index = c == ' ' ? 26 : c - 'a';
        if (current.children[index] == null) {
            previous = null;
            return history;
        }
        
        previous = current.children[index];
        traverse(query, previous, history);
        return history;
    }
    
    private void traverse(String s, TrieNode node, List<Entry> history) {
        if (node.times > 0) {
            history.add(new Entry(s, node.times));
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
            if (node.children[i] != null) {
                String next = i == 26 ? s + ' ' : s + (char) ('a' + i);
                traverse(next, node.children[i], history);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if I were to extend this solution of autocomplete on full_name to support other fields example lets say I have record as

```
Student
id:
full_name:
gender:
subject_enrolled:
```

and I want not only autocomplete search but also filter on subject_enrolled or other field.
I thought of using an inverted index to map each fields to the list of student id's they corresponds and then intersect among this with the students id's of autocomplete but its not as efficient as autocomplete.

Does anyone has any suggestion of a data structure, library that can be used more precisely I am looking for an alternate of in memory alternative for mongodb/elastic search like query support?

Comment: you don't want to use elasticsearch??

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I thought setting up an elasticsearch for this might be overkill given the scale of data.

Comment: Does the dataset change? I'm not sure what you mean by "static".

Comment: If the dataset is not changing, just keeping it in lexicographic order is much simpler (and less overhead).

Comment: yes the data is not changing, order it by full_name and do a binary search, I think for prefix search it would be fine, do you mean to iterate over the entire array for other field check linearly?